# Не генерируются assets в Yii2-advanced на новой виртуальной машине

Tags: yii2

Склонировал собственный проект на фреймфорке yii2-advanced со своего репозитория на свой второй компьютер iMac, но не срабатывает вёрстка в новом. В консоле вижу ошибки отсутствия файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На старом компе все работает.

Comment: так файлы то на месте?

Comment: Файлов действительно нет, ни в каталоге, ни на старой машине. всякий раз эта директория новая. Наверно это тонкости yii2

Comment: файлы в папке web/assets поидее можно смело удалять, при переносе  при первом запросе к сайту они должны сгенерироваться сами, у вас это не произошло. Смотрите класс AssetsBundle и его наследников, проверьте пути прописанные в классе, по идее эти файлы должны лежать в web/assets/ на которые стоят права 755 . А на папку /assets нет прав для создания файлов. Мне кажется по-этому они и не создались.

Comment: посмотрите логи машинки, есть там Permission denied?

Comment: Есть вроде - PHP message: PHP Warning:  touch(): Unable to create file /var/www/adv3/frontend/runtime/debug/index.data because Permission denied in /var/www/adv3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/src/LogTarget.php on line 85" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: frontend.test, request: "GET /assets/8da20998/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "frontend.test", referrer: "http://frontend.test/site/entry"

Comment: Класса AssetsBundle не нашёл

Comment: выставляйте  права на папки, сперва chmod -R 755 /путь до сайта/, потом chmod -R 777 /путь до сайта/runtime , потом chmod -R 777 /путь до сайта/web/assets , простите не правильно подсказал первый раз на web/assets 777 конечно, выполните эти 3 команды в консоле и посмотрите что будет

Comment: сделал, не помогло

Comment: Ведь верно же? я их ввёл ваши команды в консоль виртуальной машины. ничего не помогло. я удалял эти рандомные папки из каталога frontend/web/assets , они появлялись вновь, но в них не появляются файлы css и  js, и изначально в приложении возникает ошибка, permission denied,   но потом снова функционал появляется, а вёрстки и джаваскрипта нет